# Trailhead 'Data Leak Prevention'

Tags: trailhead

I've got an access to Kingdom Management org (as described in trail) but when I try to act with tab CRUD & FLS Visualforce Demo (just try to choose the user) I get an error - Insufficient Privileges
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Same here: to be more specific - within "Identify CRUD and FLS Violations in Visualforce and Apex" in the Data Leak Prevention module, a newly created dedicated developer org does not allow to literally follow the steps in this unit. The "CRUD Demo" should allow to view the results of running in user/system context in a custom Visualforce page. However, this fails with the aforementioned Insufficient Privileges error.

Answer (score 2):

Enable the "Administrators Can Log in as Any User" setting in Setup > Login Access Policies. Afterwards the demo works without errors.